# Object with a template key in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, templates

I need to return a typed object from the function with a **specific** key in it.
Like this:

```js
function addNumber<Key extends string>(key : Key) {
    return { [key] : 5 }
}

const a = addNumber('x')

console.log(a.x) // OK
console.log(a.y) // compilation error: y doesn't exist in a
```

Or this:

```js
function addNumber<key : string>() {
    return { [key] : 5 }
}

addNumber<'x'>() // { x : 5 }
```

I don't need a `key` to be dynamic, like any possible runtime dependent string. A compile-time literal should be enough.
But I need the function to return an object that can be type checked.

Is this possible in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there  by defining your generic and using the inference to type the result !

```
function addNumber<Key extends string>(key: Key): { [k in Key]: number; } {
  return { [key]: 5 } as { [k in Key]: number; }
}

const foo = addNumber('x')
foo.x // OK
foo.y // KO
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoHIgLYCMCmATgDwDS+AnovgB5T5ioDOiTUhMYA5gHwAUAa0oAuROQoBKUQG9EAbQGJOYygF1RYHAUIBuRAF9E0gFCJEhfFBCEkshWtEBWAyhZ3Fy8esSa8RPfrGgcYQCGyIwHBwiAC8KOhYfoR8AOQ0KRLGkXAAdDSIAPQFiADypFlROVRFYiVAA)

Comment: i think the link is corrupt

Answer (score 1):

[I got u](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwQOQK4FsBGBTATjAXhgB4BpGbADymzAQhmlwEswBzAPgAoBrALhikAlIQ4wuAbxgBtHgF0BAVhgBfeAxhTZMVoIUwwGHLgDcqoSYBQl0JFhxC8JGix4uAckruh12xBAANtgAdAEgbFxwwZQ+foEhYRFRAJ5CQA)

```
const addNumber = <K extends string>(k: K) => ({ [k]: 5 } as  { [k in K]: number; });

const a = addNumber('x'); // a: { x: number }
console.log(a.x); // ok
console.log(a.y); // Property 'y' does not exist on type '{ x: number; }'.(2339)
```

Comment: this looks like a working solution. the syntax is peculiar can you explain?

Comment: I'm using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)